# how does one implement "uniq -c" in xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I would like to count the number of identical elements in an XML,
just like `uniq -c` does for text files

Input:

```
<doc>
  <page>
    <elem>a</elem>
    <elem>a</elem>
    <elem>a</elem>
    <elem>b</elem>
    <elem>b</elem>
    <elem>c</elem>
    <elem>a</elem>
    <elem>a</elem>
  </page>
</doc>
```

Expected output:

```
<doc>
  <page>
    <elem c="3">a</elem>
    <elem c="2">b</elem>
    <elem c="1">c</elem>
    <elem c="2">a</elem>
  </page>
</doc>
```

Comment: what is your attempt ?

Answer (score 2):

In XSLT 2.0 this would be dead easy using `<xsl:for-each-group select="elem" group-adjacent=".">` but it's rather trickier in XSLT 1.0.  I'd approach it using a tail-recursive template to simulate a "while loop":

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <doc><xsl:apply-templates select="doc/page" /></doc>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="page">
    <page><xsl:apply-templates select="elem[1]" /></page>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- an element whose value is the same as the next one - don't output
       anything now, just increment counter for the next elem -->
  <xsl:template match="elem[. = following-sibling::elem[1]]">
    <xsl:param name="count" select="1" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::elem[1]">
      <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$count + 1" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- otherwise - output element with current counter value and start again
       from 1 for the next (if any) element -->
  <xsl:template match="elem">
    <xsl:param name="count" select="1" />
    <elem c="{$count}"><xsl:value-of select="." /></elem>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::elem[1]" />
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The `page` template applies templates to just the *first* `elem`, and each `elem` is then responsible for processing the next one in the chain.